# How to inject one class into another for use as a constructor in es6 classes

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, es6-class

I have a module I'd like to use called pigpio that exports a class called `Gpio`

[image]

I want to inject this class as a dependency in another class so I can use it to build GPIO instances:

```
// a simplified example of the class

import { Gpio } from "pigpio";

class PinManager {

    gpioBuilder: Gpio
    construct(builder: Gpio){
        this.gpioBuilder = builder
    }

    buildNewGpioPin(pinNumber: number, direction: number){
        return new this.gpioBuilder(pinNumber, direction)
    }
}

export default PinManager
```

The problem is, when I try to call `this.gpioBuilder` to construct the new instance of of the Gpio class I get an error telling me that there's no constructor for the class in the property:

[image]

I'm sure this is happening because es6 classes are just syntax sugar for javascript's prototype inheritance pattern, but I'm not sure how to solve for this.

I want to inject `Gpio` as a dependency so that it's easier to mock in tests, but if I can't do dependency injection this way I'm not totally sure how to do it.

## Update post correct answer

After the example given by Alex I was able to correct my class and eliminate the errors:

```
import { Gpio } from "pigpio"

class PinManager {
    gpioBuilder: typeof Gpio
    construct(builder: typeof Gpio) {
        this.gpioBuilder = builder
    }

    buildNewGpioPin(pinNumber: number, direction: number) {
        return new this.gpioBuilder(pinNumber, { mode: direction })
    }
}

export default PinManager
```

I also looked back through the typescript handbook for the explanation of why this works (I've been reading the handbook and didn't see it, turns out I just hadn't gotten to that part yet):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions

The important part being:

> ... Here we use typeof Greeter, that is “give me the type of the Greeter class itself” rather than the instance type. Or, more precisely, “give me the type of the symbol called Greeter,” which is the type of the constructor function. ...

Thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a class as type, typescript interprets that as instances of that class, and not the class constructor. You can use `typeof MyClass` if you want the constructor.

So it sounds like you want to type `gpioBuilder` as the class constructor type `typeof Gpio`.

```
import { Gpio } from "pigpio";

class PinManager {

    gpioBuilder: typeof Gpio
    constructor(builder: typeof Gpio){
        this.gpioBuilder = builder
    }

    buildNewGpioPin(pinNumber: number, direction: number){
        return new this.gpioBuilder(pinNumber, direction)
    }
}

export default PinManager
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcTMCcC+cBmUIhwBEaA5mhEQNwBQNAxgDYCGAzq3AArAB2Assx7NSAUyiI6cKXHLoAQgFdgjACZiAXHBgBPMCIg4UFGtLj0IPVjCgL6MaAAoARktUatu-YdToAlAhNTaRgAC2BWADpZCEVlNXEAXjgXOLFAqUxJaRTVADkRAHcfCG4eBzQeXIUQJ3ceatqoABo4FWAoETt0Hk16mrF-dKCOmAUoHjgeQq0wyOjYtyhy3ir+5tb2zphu3yHMzJoRAA9IWFaRHGYFRnhSgSFRKCA)

Comment: :O I've been grinding on testing and injection issues all day, this 100% fixed the issue. Thank you! I've never been so happy to hand out a check mark :P